# Displaying a list of images based on a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am so rusty and looking for assistance. I have loaded a few image files into a folder on my web server (So, uploaded them). I now want to simply display them, one underneath each other on as aspx page. So, I want to iterate through all image files in a folder, and display them on a page.

The easiest way would be a table, and then add a tr/td for each file.

Can someone advise? Would this be best? An event in my cs file that reads the folder, created as  and populate it?

This is purely for a test page, and not for production.

Comment: If its not for production, just a list would do ! and efficient too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASPX:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" CellPadding="5">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image Width="100" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/images/{0}") %>' runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/images/{0}") %>' runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
</asp:DataList>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListImages();
    }

    private void ListImages()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("~/images"));
        FileInfo[] file = dir.GetFiles();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        foreach (FileInfo file2 in file)
        {
            if (file2.Extension == ".jpg" || file2.Extension == ".jpeg" || file2.Extension == ".gif")
            {
                list.Add(file2);
            }
        }
        DataList1.DataSource = list;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
```

Add whatever extensions you need !

[Source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1110308.aspx/1)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    private string url;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        url = PictureManager.MembersImagesPath + tuMember.PhotoBig;
        Page.DataBind();
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="210px" Width="252px" ImageUrl="<%#url%>" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: That's 100% perfect - thanks! One question - I need the ImageUrl in the asp to be a variable. Is that possible? At the moment, you have it hard coded to "~/images". I have a path variable which my code behind uses (So I replaced the hard coded URL in ListImages()), but can I use the same variable in the aspx?

Answer (score 2):

For a straight HTML approach, you can use:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            const string SUBDIR = "images";

            foreach (string fileName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(SUBDIR)))
            {
                var oRow = new HtmlTableRow();
                var oCell = new HtmlTableCell();

                var oHREF = new HtmlAnchor();
                string actualFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                oHREF.HRef = Request.ApplicationPath + "//" + SUBDIR + "//" + actualFileName;
                oHREF.InnerText = actualFileName;

                oCell.Controls.Add(oHREF);

                oRow.Cells.Add(oCell);

                tblImages.Rows.Add(oRow);
            }
        }
    }
```